# Annual New Year crowdfunding campaigns

Tags: discussion

Idea: Math.SE sets up annual New Year crowdfunding campaigns which last, say, a month, and the money raised is then split up proportionally (to users' reputation points aquired since the beginning of the last year) between, say, Top-10 users and sent to them via, say, PayPal.

This would be a nice Christmas gift to the best annual contributors. I am sure many people (including me) will be more than happy to send a dollar or two.

What do you think?

Comment: Now, the only people who will upvote are the current Top-10 users :-P

Comment: Why would you think that reputation directly correlates to how valuable any particular user is to this site? I look at someone like [Martin Sleziak](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/8297/martin-sleziak) who doesn't even post very much (let alone rake in tons of reputation), but whose commitment to tidying up the site (both main and meta) is pretty much invaluable.

Comment: Reputation _should_ directly correlate with person's contribution level. I am very sad to hear that it is not the case on this website.

Comment: Reputation is proportional to how many "hard" calculus questions you can stomach...

Comment: @user1729 No, the really hard calculus questions don't get too much rep either. The easy-but-not-obvious ones get you a ton of upvotes.

Comment: @Daniel Exactly - "hard".

Comment: I would appreciate it if somebody would actually answer the question fully instead of silently downvoting it and upvoting comments that answer the question only partially.

Comment: @ArthurFischer Agreed. Martin for moderator.

Comment: @ArthurFischer I appreciate this, but I would point out that for some time I am not as active on the main site as I used to be. (Both in posts and in admin - or whatever I should call editing, retagging and similar stuff.) I would say that [this list](http://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=participation) has quite good correlation with the users who tend to do such things. (It should be *combined number of posts, votes, comments and edits*. I am not sure what time period is taken into consideration.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Your administrative work extends beyond the editing of posts (and despite your lowered activity, you are _still_ among the top 20 editors for Nov 2014, and the only one among the top 36 who has gained less than 200 reputation for this period). You also keep many of our neglected chatrooms unfrozen, for instance. I still think you've got one of the highest work/reward ratios on the site (unfortunately). (The main participation rating is probably calculated like [meta participation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149097/214632).)

Answer (score 6):

I like the idea of doing something nice for our best contributors (whoever those may be), but I don't think it should be about money.  Money tends to drive people apart.  Whichever standards we decide on, the contributors who do not make the cut will feel bad, like they are not valued by the community.  Also, many of us are in college or grad school, and don't have any money.  It would make us feel left out if we couldn't contribute to the gift.

Maybe there is something else that we could do to show our appreciation for our favorite other users without making anyone feel left out or jealous.

Comment: Yes, and I just thought of such a thing. One could show appreciation by upvoting their posts. Neat idea, isn't it?

Comment: @Rafflesiaarnoldii Indeed.